# How to perform SUM of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have a table called `temp_reading`. It has the following columns (consumption is an index key):

```
id consumption total
1  100
1  200
1  300
1  400
2  50
2  100
3  200
4  250
```

Now I want to display total as

```
id   consumption  total
1    100          100
1    200          300
1    300          600
1    300          900
2    50           50
2    100          150
3    200          200
4    250          250
```

Is it possible to display like the above?

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT id,consumption,sum(consumption) as total 
FROM temp_reading 
GROUP BY consumption;
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Can't you do this application-side? This is awkward to do in pure SQL.

Comment: yes i can do this in application side can you please explain me  how to do this in application side

Comment: what is programming language used by your application?

Comment: my application includes java ,jsp and mysql

Comment: @SaiSai Check my answer. It will done database side and more effective.

Comment: @SaiSai Had you checked my answer? Let me know that it's right or wrong.

Comment: thanks for your reply saharsh i tried it but i didn't get the result

Comment: thank you so much for your reply saharsh it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, consumption, IF(@s=@s:=id, @s2:=@s2+consumption, @s2:=consumption) AS total
FROM temp_reading, (SELECT @s:=0, @s2:=0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you add a `Primary Key` on your `temp_reading` table. (Read more about [Primary Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)) This key will be unique per row. Then you can try this query:

```
SELECT TR.id
  , TR.consumption
  , TR.consumption + IFNULL(SUM(TR2.consumption), 0) AS Total
  FROM temp_reading TR
  LEFT JOIN temp_reading TR2 ON TR.id = TR2.id AND TR.pk > TR2.pk
  GROUP BY TR.pk;
```

I've tried it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9899b/11).

Answer (score 1):

```
     select id,sum(consumption) as total 
     from temp_reading 
     group by id;
```

I suggest you do not have the same `ID` (1,1,1.2,2...)